# How do I avoid using !important?

Tags: css, fonts, media

I am trying to make my website responsive. However, when I use another media query, a lot of things won't work. For example:

(Normal CSS)

```css
div#divName
{
    font-size:1em;
}
```

(Media query code)

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) 
{
    div#divName
    {
        font-size:.5em;
    }
}
```

This doesn't work. It only works when I use "!important" behind it. But I don't know if that is correct or "wrong". Could anyone tell me how I can fix this?

Comment: If you want to get around using `!important` you'll just need a slightly better understanding of the cascade that happens in CSS :)

Comment: try using classes on your css/html instead of ID's. try to use ID's in html only when you are going to be attaching javascript events etc

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my CSS media query being ignored?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277651/why-is-my-css-media-query-being-ignored)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

All `!important` does is increase [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity). To avoid using `!important`, all you need to do is increase specificity.

In your case, both of your selectors have identical specificity. The issue is most likely caused by your media query being placed *before* your "Normal CSS", and thus getting overridden.

1. If they're in the same CSS file, ensure your "Normal CSS" is placed before your media query.
2. If they're in different CSS files, ensure the file containing your media query is included in your HTML document *after* your "Normal CSS".

Comment: Cheers mate! Thank you very much! I did have all media queries above the original code.

Answer (score 1):

make sure your CSS rules that you want to override loads after.
in your case

```
div#divName
{
    font-size:1em;
}
```

should be loaded first and after that:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) 
{
    div#divName
    {
        font-size:.5em;
    }
}
```

you want to have two separated files `style.css` and `responsive.css` and include them in following order:

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
<link href="responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```