# Make CSS Hover work when the element is hidden using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a menu where there are the heading and the submenus. Whenever the user hovers over the heading, submenus show up.

And whenever any of the items in submenus is clicked, the submenu is set to hidden using Javascript. Now, when the user hovers over the menu, the submenus don't show up! Please help me to fix this.

```js
function closesSan() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('submenu')[0].style.setProperty('display', 'none', 'important');
}
```

```css
#main:hover .submenu {
  display: block!important;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="main">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">List</a>
    <ul class="submenu" style="display: none;">
      <li onclick="closesSan()">Bacon</li>
      <li onclick="closesSan()">Tuna</li>
      <li onclick="closesSan()">Chicken</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Every ‘important’ kills a kitten

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to write some additional code to get the desired result. Actually, the base problem in your code was `important` and `property` {both works same} in sense both get prioritized by code.

So to get rid of I have added an additional class on click and removing that class on every new hover. Hope it will satisfy the needs.

```js
var main = document.getElementById("main");
main.onmouseover = function() {
  document.querySelector('.submenu').classList.remove("displayNoneImp");
}

function closesSan() {
  document.querySelector('.submenu').classList.add("displayNoneImp");
}
```

```css
.submenu {
  display: none;
}

#main:hover .submenu {
  display: block;
}

.displayNoneImp {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="main">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">List</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li onclick="closesSan()">Bacon</li>
      <li onclick="closesSan()">Tuna</li>
      <li onclick="closesSan()">Chicken</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That helped a lot! Thank you

Comment: Don't mention it anytime

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't use a pure CSS implementation, use [**`event listeners`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and avoid using [**`!important`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27443589/how-do-i-avoid-using-important) whenever possible:

```js
var main = document.querySelector('#main');
var submenu = document.querySelector('.submenu');
var items = document.querySelectorAll('#main li');

main.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {  
  submenu.style.display = 'block';
});

main.addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
  submenu.style.display = 'none';
});

items.forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function () {
    console.log('clicked on:', item)
    submenu.style.display = 'none';
  });
});
```

```css
.submenu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="main">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">List</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li>Bacon</li>
      <li>Tuna</li>
      <li>Chicken</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[**When Using !important is The Right Choice**](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something simple like this:

```js
function closesSan() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('submenu')[0].classList.add("hide");
  setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementsByClassName('submenu')[0].classList.remove("hide");
  },100)
}
```

```css
#main .submenu {
  display: none;
}

#main:hover .submenu {
  display: block;
}
#main .submenu.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="main">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">List</a>
    <ul class="submenu" >
      <li onclick="closesSan()" >Bacon</li>
      <li onclick="closesSan()">Tuna</li>
      <li onclick="closesSan()">Chicken</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

use visibility instead of display

```
visibility: hidden;
```

save those kittens

Comment: Unfortunately, the submenu would still claim rendering space.

Comment: well if that is what you need then hover would need to be done in JS to change the display property

Comment: try,
    .submenu:hover . {
  display: block;
}