# How to remove background color on hover of bar in highcharts

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts

I am using [highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/). Version: `9.1.1`

I am displaying bar chart. When I hover on `bars` it display `background color` but I don't want that background color.

As we can see in below image I don't want that `grey` color by hover on `green bar`.

[image]

I applied this solution but it disable tooltip also. but I need tooltip on hover.

```
plotOptions: { 
       series: {
          enableMouseTracking: false
       }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Rohit Tagadiya, Could you adapt this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/oazfkxdn/ to show the problem? As you can see, it works fine with basic options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By taking reference of @Robart. I inspect chart and modified class `.highcharts-crosshair-category` style

I applied below style

```
.highcharts-crosshair-category {
   display: none !important;
   visibility: hidden !important;
 }
```

Comment: To use !important is not a good approach. In my example, I used all these classes to avoid using !important. So, take a look before .highcharts-crosshair-category, and see if there are other classes defined and use them as in my example.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27443589/how-do-i-avoid-using-important

Answer (score 2):

I would check to see the classes used for these charts.

Once you found the class of your charts you can modify them in the .css file.

```
<li class="class1">
                <a class="class2">
                    <span class="class3"></span>
```

Let's say you have something like this but the span in your case would be the chart.
In this case in the.css file you have to do something like this:

```
.class1 .class2 .class3:hover {
    background: none; 
}
```

Using the browser tools you can also simulate(force) a hover and do there some changes.

Comment: Will check it out. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Make this change in chartOption: crosshair: false

Comment: This does not answer the question.