# Display the text inside the div carousel indicators

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have 3 tabs designed from the bootstrap carousel. The tabs need to be named as Step1, 2 and 3.

I have placed names Step 1, 2 and 3 respectively in the carousel-indicator divs but its not appearing. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```html
<style>
.carousel-indicators {
  display: flex!important;
  position: inherit!important;
  justify-content: space-between!important;
}

.carousel-indicators [data-bs-target] {flex: 1 0 auto!important;} 
.carousel-indicators {  margin-left: auto!important;  margin-right: auto!important;}


.carousel-indicators .active {
 border-bottom: blue 5px solid!important;
}

.page{
    height:50px!important;
    background:#efefef!important;
    margin:0px!important;
}
</style>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
      <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
        <input class="workflowTitle" value="Accordion Item #1" />
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">

        <div id="carouselExampleDark" class="carousel carousel-dark slide" data-bs-ride="false" data-bs-interval="false">

          <div class="carousel-indicators">



            <div type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="page active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1">Step1</div>
            <div type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="1" class="page" aria-label="Slide 2">Step2</div>
            <div type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="2" class="page" aria-label="Slide 3">Step3</div>




          </div>

          <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="false" data-bs-wrap="false">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                <p class="d-block w-100">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.



                </p>
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <p class="d-block w-100">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.



                </p>
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <p class="d-block w-100">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
                </p>
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <button class="btn btn-light" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide="prev">
            <span class="">Previous</span>
          </button>
            <button class="btn btn-light" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide="next">

            <span class="">Next</span>
          </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text is not visible because of the `text-indent` property being set to `-999px`. The fix would be to add it to the indicator with the target attribute as follows `.carousel-indicators [data-bs-target] {  text-indent: 0!important; }`.

You can see this working below along with a few additional styles I've added to center the text. Disclaimer: not all of the styles may be required so feel free to tinker and keep what you need.

```css
.carousel-indicators [data-bs-target] {
  flex: 1 0 auto!important;
  text-indent: 0!important;
  display: flex!important;
  justify-content: center!important;
  align-items: center!important;
}
```

I have kept `!important` in my examples to match the code style, but personally, I would remove the usages of `!important` everywhere and instead try to increase specificity another way. See [How do I avoid using !important?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27443589/how-do-i-avoid-using-important) and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

```css
.carousel-indicators {
  display: flex!important;
  position: inherit!important;
  justify-content: space-between!important;
}

.carousel-indicators [data-bs-target] {
  flex: 1 0 auto!important;
  text-indent: 0!important;
  display: flex!important;
  justify-content: center!important;
  align-items: center!important;
}

.carousel-indicators {
  margin-left: auto!important;
  margin-right: auto!important;
}

.carousel-indicators .active {
  border-bottom: blue 5px solid!important;
}

.page {
  height: 50px!important;
  background: #efefef!important;
  margin: 0px!important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
      <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
        <input class="workflowTitle" value="Accordion Item #1" />
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <div id="carouselExampleDark" class="carousel carousel-dark slide" data-bs-ride="false" data-bs-interval="false">
          <div class="carousel-indicators">
            <div type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="page active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1">
              Step1
            </div>
            <div type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="1" class="page" aria-label="Slide 2">
              Step2
            </div>
            <div type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="2" class="page" aria-label="Slide 3">
              Step3
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="false" data-bs-wrap="false">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                <p class="d-block w-100">
                  Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
                  one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of
                  "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                  amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
                </p>
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <p class="d-block w-100">
                  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
                  survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
                  with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                </p>
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <p class="d-block w-100">
                  It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here,
                  content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.
                  Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
                </p>
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block"></div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <button class="btn btn-light" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide="prev">
              <span class="">Previous</span>
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-light" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide="next">
              <span class="">Next</span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```